# mysql timediff to hours

Tags: php, mysql

I'm Trying to get the timediff from my table and convert it to hours (it's for an hourly billed service)

> SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(endDate,startDate))/3600 FROM tasks >

where endDate and startDate are in datetime format

is there another way (more efficient) to do this task?
Thanks !

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621440/mysql-how-to-get-exact-difference-of-hours-between-two-dates).

Comment: I think everyone missed a very importantpoint here - because it's non-techie. Things billed by the hours are nornally billed by the hour **started**, not **completed**. So, all of these answers probably need to round up. E.g, 1 hour 1 minute == 2 hours billable (just like paying to park your car, etc)

Answer (score 54):

`TIMEDIFF(endDate, startDate)` outputs in DateTime format, so flat that to timestamp and devide by (60*60)

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMEDIFF(endDate, startDate))/(60*60)) AS hours_difference
FROM tasks
```

***Edit:*** Alternatively,[TimestampDiff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) may also provide a valid solution in more elegant way providing its example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01');
```

And your solution can be:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, startDate, endDate) AS hours_different
FROM tasks
```

Comment: Correct parameters ```TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, startDate, endDate)```

Comment: Oddly, UNIX_TIMESTAMP returns 0 and TimeStampDiff returns NULL for all values in MySQL Version ~5.0 (very out of date).  OP's approach worked in that case.

Comment: Note that `TIMEDIFF` and `TIMESTAMPDIFF` do not account for daylight savings changes. @Donny Kurnia's answer below works best if the hour gained/lost is of importance in your case.

Answer (score 42):

NOTE the most voted up answer in this chain is INCORRECT! Using HOUR will only return hours as an integer. Below would correct the most popular answer to return hours as an integer and minutes as a decimal (ie 6.5 hours).

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(endDate, startDate))/3600 as hours
```

Comment: In which case, as OP says "it's for an hourly billed service", I imagine that you would want to round any fraction upwards to the next whole hour. So, yes, the other guy might be wrong, because he returns an INTEGER, but it sounds like OP wants an integer **rounded up**

Comment: Semantics, "hourly" work billed to the half hour or other fraction is not an unusual thing. Why not cover all bases at once?

Answer (score 13):

```
HOUR(TIMEDIFF(endDate, startDate))
```

might work—if I'm reading the docs correctly.

Comment: Don't forget that this function rounding

Answer (score 12):

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, startDate, endDate)
```

is the best way to do it, because it works with big time intervals, like

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, "2012-01-01 00:00:00", "2050-01-01 00:00:00")
```

Result: `333120`

while

```
HOUR(TIMEDIFF("2050-01-01 00:00:00", "2012-01-01 00:00:00"))
```

Result: `838`

fails.

As we see in the example above, it surprisingly even works beyond the timestamp limitation in year 2038.

The maximum hours which are returned by `HOUR(TIMEDIFF(dateEnd, dateStart))` is 838, because `TIMEDIFF` is limited to the range allowed for `TIME` values.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to do the calculation in SELECT query.

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(endDate)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(startDate))/3600 hour_diff
  FROM tasks
```

[UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) convert datetime to number of second from epoch. You can substract both timestamp to get difference in second. Divide it with 3600 will give you difference in hour.

Comment: Best answer for accuracy - `TIMEDIFF` and `TIMESTAMPDIFF` don't account for daylight savings time changes.

Comment: as said in previous comment, this accounts for DST, which is awesome!

Comment: @RogerDueck, @Gusmar I'm not seeing how it accounts for daylight savings...
With this SQL, I still get 12 (when I should get 13): `SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-11-04 07:00:00')-UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-11-03 19:00:00')) / 3600 hourDiff;`

Comment: @RogerDueck Nevermind. You both are right, but one's database's or db sesson's timezone needs to be set to a timezone that observes daylight savings. For example, UTC does not observe DLS.

Answer (score 7):

for getting Diffrence in Hour :

```
Hour(TIMEDIFF(date1,date2)) as Hour1
```

for getting Diffrence in Minute :

```
Minute(TIMEDIFF(date1,date2)) as Minute1
```

for getting Diffrence in Second :

```
Second(TIMEDIFF(date1,date2)) as Second1
```

Comment: I think this is partly incorrect? The minute and second functions do not return the time as minutes or seconds. They return the minute or second part of the value. So for example the "second" function always returns a value between 0 and 59. "Hour" seems to behave differently http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_second

Comment: I have a time difference of 65 hours and 42 minutes, the Hour() function returns 65 hours exactly, the Minute() function returns 42 minutes. If that's what you want, great, I was hoping for 65.7 hours from Hour() and 3942 minutes from Minute() so the timestamp method is more use to me

Answer (score 5):

eg: startDate 2010-01-31 00:00:00, endDate 2010-01-31 19:24:22

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateFin)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateDebut))/3600 hour_diff
FROM tasks

SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(endDate,startDate))/3600
FROM tasks
```

returns 19.4061 which is good

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, endDate, startDate) AS hours_different
FROM tasks
```

Only returns hours while i also need minutes to be converted.

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMEDIFF(endDate, startDate))/(60*60)) AS hours_difference
FROM tasks
```

returns 0.
I think the first one is the most efficent. Thanks !!

Comment: You should choose one of the answers as accepted, instead of create answers like this. Also, use comment in the appropiate answers, instead of rewrite or re-quote.

Comment: SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(endDate,startDate))/3600
FROM tasks  is a good one

Answer (score 4):

you can use mysql funcion timestampdiff like below

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2018-06-01 00:00:00', '2018-06-01 12:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select hour(timediff('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2017-01-01 00:01:00'));
 return 1

select hour(timediff('2017-01-01 00:01:00', '2017-01-01 00:00:00'));
 return 1 

select time_to_sec(timediff('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2017-01-01 00:00:05'));
return -5

select time_to_sec(timediff('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2017-01-01 00:00:05'))/60 as 'minutes' ;
return -0.0833
```

if you have the seconds you can convert it as you want or what
and hours(..) will not use it when i compare because it's always postive value

Answer (score 0):

```
TIMEDIFF(endDate, startDate) / 10000
```