# How to get the difference between two dates rounded to hours

Tags: sql, mysql

I'll illustrate what I would like to get in the following example:

```
'2010-09-01 03:00:00' - '2010-09-01 00:10:00'
```

Using `TIMEDIFF()`, we get 2 as a result. This means, it's not considering the 50 minutes left.

In this case, what I'd like to get is: 50 (minutes) / 60 = 0.83 period. Therefore, the result should be 2.83 and not 2.

Comment: Are you casting to an integer? You should get a time result back, like '2:50:00'.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

```
select time_to_sec(timediff('2010-09-01 03:00:00', '2010-09-01 00:10:00' )) / 3600;

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| time_to_sec(timediff('2010-09-01 03:00:00', '2010-09-01 00:10:00' )) / 3600 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                      2.8333 | 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: timediff solution has a problem: it can not have value more than 839 hours (minus 1 second). So it will not be able to find a difference with more than ~35 days

Comment: I just had a bug because of this. This solution is not reliable.

Answer (score 24):

Use TIMESTAMPDIFF for exact number of hours :

```
SELECT 
      b.`Start_Date`, 
      b.`End_Date`, 
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, b.`Start_Date`, b.`End_Date`) AS `HOURS` 
FROM my_table b;
```

Answer (score 21):

I think a more complete answer is

```
select time_format(timediff(onedateinstring,anotherdateinstring),'%H:%i:%s')
```

This allows you to see the hours, minutes, seconds, etc. that you wish to see in the format you want...

More information on time_format: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format

Answer (score 13):

You could try the following:

```
time_format(timediff(max(l.fecha), min(l.fecha) ),'%H:%m') //Hora y minutos
```

Comment: Este sitio es Inglés. Su ayuda se agradece, pero por favor, tratar de publicar las respuestas en Inglés.

Comment: the important part of it was (no hablo espan~ol, but I understod hsi answer) :-/

Comment: You reposted in the wrong neighborhood, but your intentions are appreciated anyway. Tome su voto a favor.

Comment: Works perfectly, except that in the version I'm using at least (5.7), it's '%i' for minutes, not '%m': https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_time_format.asp

Answer (score 9):

Its a very old thread, but you can also try TIMESTAMPDIFF and give MINUTE, HOUR, SECONDS as the qualifier.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Answer (score 5):

MySQL get the number of hours between timestamps:

```
select timestampdiff(second,'2010-09-01 00:10:00', '2010-09-01 03:00:00')/3600;
```

Comment: Why not `timestampdiff(hour,'2010-09-01 00:10:00', '2010-09-01 03:00:00')`?

Comment: It doesn't take into account the minutes. The one you suggested returns answer as 2, whereas the above solution gives 2.83 (0.83 hours is the difference of 50 minutes)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2010-09-01 03:00:00', '2010-09-01 00:10:00')) / 3600)
```

> Result: 2.8333

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using timestamp, this could be the solution in MySQL using SQL.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2010-11-29 13:13:55', '2010-11-29 13:16:55') as newtable;

| newtable |

7

1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using UNIX_TIMESTAMP:

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(End)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Start))/3600
AS Difference_in_hours 
FROM Table
```