# PHP/MySQL check for ip if availabe in past 24 hours using time()

Tags: php, mysqli, ip

Database:

```
pub_id pub_name time              ip
1      King     1359500087        3388636152
2      Queen    1359550082        6385394932
3      Jack     1359502084        5648646562
4      Heart    1359524083        9283834142
5      Jim      1359503082        3388636152
                |_ Using time()    |_ Using ip2long()
```

PHP/MySQLi Code:

```
$pub_id = $_GET['pub_id'];
$pub_name = $_GET['pub_name'];
$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$time = time();

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM impressions WHERE pub_id = '$pub_id' AND pub_name = '$pub_name' AND ip = '$ip' AND time >= '???'");
$ip_adderss = $query->num_rows;
$query->close();

if($ip_adderss == 0){
// Redirect
} else{
// Do nothing
}
```

Now using the time() and IP how can i check that the current visitor last visit was 24 hour ago or not?

A simple solution is using if statement to check the ip time and now time.

```
// Check if the IP is new or returning
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM impressions WHERE pub_id = '$pub_id' AND pub_tag = '$pub_tag' AND month = '$month' AND day = '$day' AND ip = '$ip' AND domain = '$domain' AND valid = '1' ORDER BY id DESC");

$ip_address = $query->num_rows;

if($ip_address == 0){

    $ip_ok = 1;

} elseif($ip_address != 0){

    $impression = $query->fetch_assoc();

    if($time >= ($impression['time'] + 86400)){

        $ip_ok = 1;

    } else{

        $ip_ok = 0;

    }

} else{

$ip_ok = 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you calculate how many seconds in a day?

Comment: Its just for example Im not going to use the same code...

Comment: You dont really need PHP for that.It can be done using MYSQL only

Comment: I know that if you see the code in mysql query i have put time >= ??? but how?

Comment: read this.MySql has many functions to do so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621440/mysql-how-to-get-exact-difference-of-hours-between-two-dates

Comment: Really liked your profile and ideas @YourCommonSense :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `time` field contains unix timestamp, which is just a number of seconds.
So, it's easy to calculate a point that lies a day ago - just subtract  86400 from the current timestamp.
So, your condition is going to be as simple as an elementary school math:

```
WHERE time >= unix_timestamp() - 86400
```

or, if you want it using `time()` PHP function

```
$time  = time() - 86400;
$query = "SELECT * FROM impressions WHERE ... AND time >= ?");
```

and then bind that value.