# How to check how many hours of two datetimes is between a fixed timerange

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

**I have the following situation:**

I have the a timerange from 17h to 22h.

E.g. then I have a row with the following informations:

```
Starttime (datetime): 2020-03-16 13:15:00
Endtime (datetime): 2020-03-16 19:45:00
```

How can I get the number of hours which is between the fixed timerange (--> 2:45h)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two dates rounded to hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621440/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-rounded-to-hours)

Comment: No, this is the answer to get the difference between two datetimes - I want to know the difference between two datetimes IN a fixed timerange.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Get the difference in the two timestamps and then use a WHERE clause to filter the selection so that difference less than 225 minutes (that’s 2h 45m as per your requirement).

Comment: @itranger A min-max may solve that part of your Q (pseudo-code): `min(end_range, end_time) - max(start_range, start_time)`, assuming end > start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that start/end time do not span over days, you can use `timediff()`, `greatest()` and `least()`:

```
select timediff(
    greatest(time(start_time), '17:00:00'),
    least(time(endtime), '22:00:00')
)
```

`greatest(time(start_time), '17:00:00')` gives you 17h if the (time component of) `start_time` is less than 17h.

`least(time(endtime), '22:00:00'` produces 22h if the end time is greater than 22h.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer. I have a question by the following entry: 
Starttime (datetime): 2020-03-21 00:00:00
Endtime (datetime): 2020-03-21 02:04:42 

It returns 14:55:18.000000 but it should return NULL because the time is not between 17h and 22h