# Convert TIMEDIFF to hours plus minutes

Tags: php, mysql, minute

```
time1: 2013-08-26 16:33:00  
time2: 2013-08-26 15:10:00

$query="UPDATE `FlightSchedule` 
SET delay = MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(time1, time2)) 
WHERE `flightNum_arr`='".$flightNum_arr."';";
```

It saves the value 23 as the delay. Instead the correct answer should be 83 minutes. How to get it?

Comment: do the same to the `hours` as well, multiply the `hour` diff by `60` and add it to your `delay`...

Comment: this might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174058/mysql-timediff-to-hours

Comment: I really hope that `$flightNum_arr` is [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/) because when you see things like this, using string concatenation to compose queries, virtually every time it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
$query="UPDATE `FlightSchedule` 
SET delay = CEIL((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time1) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time2))/60)
WHERE `flightNum_arr`='".$flightNum_arr."';";
```

Alternatively, there is [TIME_TO_SEC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) function - and, since it provides result in seconds, you'll need to divide it to 60 too.

Answer (score 4):

It returns `1 hour 23 min`. You have to get hour.

Following codes return `4980` sec. And you have to divide 60 for minutes.

You can use `TIME_TO_SEC`

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time1, time2)) / 60
```

Comment: It's strange but in my case it says "Query returned no resultset". No entries have been saved. UPDATE `FlightSchedule` SET delay = TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time1,time2))/60 WHERE `flightNum_arr`='3911';

Comment: Could you run on phpMyadmin directly?

Comment: Yes, I did it. The result is the same.

Comment: You can try with `ceil` like: `CEIL(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time1, time2)) / 60)`