# How to convert time format in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a five outputs like here (this is query `TIMEDIFF(out_time, in_time)`)->`9:04:04, 8:56:16, 9:43:09, 9:40:03`

when i use this `SUM(TIMEDIFF(out_time, in_time)) as 'Working hours'` query to get sum of this times i will get **364332** but what i want is time format **37:23:32** is there any code to do for that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql timediff to hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174058/mysql-timediff-to-hours)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579946/only-show-hours-in-mysql-datediff

Comment: both not working @Panky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is i have did its working

```
CONCAT(
FLOOR(
SUM(CASE WHEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time))<=0 THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time))=''
ELSE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time)) END)/3600) ,':',
FLOOR(MOD(
SUM(CASE WHEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time))<=0 THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time))=''
ELSE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,in_time)) END),3600)/60)) as 'WORKING HOURS'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL function [SEC_TO_TIME()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-sec_to_time-function.php)

`SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(out_time, in_time))) as Working hours`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(out_time, in_time))) ,'%H:%i:%s') as 'Working hours'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(out_time, in_time)))) AS workingHours
```

Comment: 1/4/1900 5:12:12 AM :( this is wht im gettting

Comment: Try removing first `SEC_TO_TIME()` like `Select SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(out_time, in_time))) AS workingHours`
then you get time in terms of second you just have to convert it to hours.